# How to make a linux dialog utility menu with side by side choices?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog

Which options do I use to make a dialog menu display in more than one column?

This:

```
dialog --title "[ M A I N - M E N U ]" \
        --menu "Please choose an option:" 15 55 5 \
            1 "View the config file" \
            2 "Edit config file" \
            3 "Exit"
```

Displays everything in one column

```
1 View the config file
2 Edit config file
3 Exit
```

How do I have it display as:

```
1 View the config file                  2 Edit config file
3 Exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Dialog Menu is designed to be in vertical fashion.
Selection of menu falls in UP/DOWN manner.
two options in a single row is not possible.